# CSS display: flex, align-center and button with checkboxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a flex box with buttons and a label inside. Apparently `align-items` property does not align buttons. How can I achieve that?

https://jsfiddle.net/elaman/4uyggo7s/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <button>Test</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
        <label for="test">Test</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Test</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.wrapper > * {
    align-items: baseline;
}
.wrapper > :first-child {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.wrapper button {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**Update:** I'm searching the way to vertically align label, checkbox and button to the single baseline.

Comment: I'm confused with what you're asking for here. Could you possibly add an image depicting what you wish to achieve?

Comment: I found this link: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/smarter-input-groups-flexbox/. Basically if I add  `.wrapper > * { display: inline-flex; }` it gives the result I need. But I'm still not sure about it, so will do some more tests.

Comment: What is `align-center`?

Comment: @Oriol sorry, `align-items`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) property applies to flex containers, not flex items.

So you should apply it to `.wrapper` instead of `.wrapper > *`:

```css
.wrapper {
  align-items: baseline; /* Align the baselines of the flex items */
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
.wrapper > :first-child {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.wrapper button {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
    <label for="test">Test</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Moreover, I suggest simplifying the markup, removing unnecessary inner wrappers:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;         /* Magic begins */
  align-items: baseline; /* Align the baselines of the flex items */
}
.wrapper > :first-child {
  margin-right: auto;    /* Push following flex items to the right */
}
.wrapper button {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Test</button>
  <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
  <label for="test">Test</label>
  <button>Test</button>
  <button>Test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This one actually works and it aligns to the baseline, not the centre. The layout is predefined by CMS. Thanks.